# Automatic CRUD with LINQ using BindingSource and Grid

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagrid, crud

I have a GridView bound to a BindingSource. My LINQ entity relationship is simple:
Customer -> Orders.

So binding is simple, too: `BindingSource source = new BindingSource(context, "Customers");`

When I add a new row on the grid for the customer, the AddingNew event fires and it automatically inserts. However, when I expand the Customers node (its a hierarchical grid) and add a new order row, the AddingNew event doesn't fire on the binding source at all.

If I switch the binding source to:
`BindingSource source = new BindingSource(context, "Orders");` then I don't get my customers obviously, but inserting a new order works fine too.

Something tells me that it's not supporting the relationship properly or something. What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, the grid i'm using is Telerik's RadGridView with hierarchical view. I doubt this is where the problem lies because it displays the master details just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by defining the Relations property of the grid.